# VBA .Range Two Brackets or Parentheses

Tags: excel, vba, syntax

Trying to work with an existing piece of VBA code and trying to figure out what this piece is doing. It is referring to certain cells but I would like to know the syntax please.

This is from an existing piece of code I'm trying to update.

```
FilePath = ActiveSheet.Range("rng_File_Path")(iRow, 1).Value
```

What do the side by side parentheses do in the .Range function?

Comment: It's assigning the value of a cell to the variable `FilePath`. The cell in the `iRow`th row (and first column) of named range "rng_File_Path".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access the `(irow,1)` th Value of the `Range("rng_File_Path")`

**For example if I have a Range that refers as:**

```
 rng_File_Path = Range("A1:A4")
```

**then:**

`Range("rng_File_Path")(2,1)` will give me `A2`

Answer (score 2):

It is equaivalent to:

```
FilePath = ActiveSheet.Range("rng_File_Path").Cells(iRow, 1).Value
```

Comment: Thank you - makes sense

Comment: @mburn23 - If this answers your question, please then accept it :-)

Answer (score 0):

- `ActiveSheet`: Refer to the sheet which is activated at the point the code executed
- `Range("rng_File_Path")`: Refer to a range which is called "rng_File_Path". You could find the exact range address in: Formulas Tab - Defined Names - Name Manager
- `.Cells(iRow, 1)`: Refer to the cell with row - iRow (iRow most propably takes its value from a loop)  & column 1 from "rng_File_Path"

In my opinion, looping a named range using this approach is wrong. Let's say the named range has 4 rows and 3 columns and you refer to `.Range("rng_File_Path").Cells(20, 10).Value`. The answer will be `Nothing` instead of error. The named range has only 4 rows (you are looking for row no. 20) and 3 columns (you are looking for column no. 10)